# WriteFile and Issue on startup

Tags: delphi

well I'm unable to write file if application Run auto at start-up but when i click normally by double click on application it create file normally even i'm using Wind7UAC.manifest running application as admin. what is wrong ? not getting this ***WriteLN('WriteFile True');*** it means issue is with ***WriteFile***

```
    Procedure CFile(FileName: String; imagem: string; Size: DWORD);
    var
      hFile: THandle;
      lpNumberOfBytesWritten: DWORD;
    begin
      hFile := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, 0);
      if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      begin
        if Size = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
      if  WriteFile(hFile, imagem[1], Size, lpNumberOfBytesWritten, nil) = true then
      WriteLN('WriteFile True');
        CloseHandle(hFile);
      end else WriteLN('Cannot Create File !');
    end;
```

Comment: which directory are you writing to?

Comment: C:\Program Files i think only windows32 and Program Files folder have access i have read some where in MSDN library? and my UAC is disabled

Comment: you don't have write access to those folders

Comment: then which folder should i select for all users folder ? is there any way to get access pragmatically ?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the working directory is the Windows directory when you auto start an app. You don't have permission to write there (unless you disable UAC).

I recommend you use a full absolute path when you open your file rather than a relative path as at present. Use SHGetSpecialFolderPath to find the location of an appropriate folder,

Comment: By the way, you should accept the best answer to your questions. I see you are new and probably haven't quite caught on yet. Please see the [faq]

Comment: what is use of UAC manifest then ? i mean I'm using in my application but still it block out ?

Comment: Which auto start mechanism did you use? I'm not sure what MS does with auto start but I would not be at all surprised if the policy was that UAC dialogs are not shown for auto start processes. In any case, I thought you said that you had disabled UAC on the machine you are testing on. P.S. Thanks for the accept. You may wish to review your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This might be Windows User Account Control (UAC) blocking your program on startup. You might have to create a Task to launch it. [This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616) contains details.